# plsql stops running after the first loop (Error: "Subscript outside of limit")

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE Lname IS VARRAY(15)
        OF employees.last_name%TYPE;
        v1 Lname:= Lname();
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT employee_id
        FROM employees
        WHERE department_id = 50;

    LEN NUMBER(2);
    I NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
    -- Print out the contents of this Varray while populating
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This printout is in order of populating:');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || 'Name');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || '----');
    I := 1;
    FOR E IN c1 LOOP
        v1.EXTEND();
        v1(I) := e.employee_id;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || v1(I));
        I := I + 1;
    END LOOP;

    -- Display the maximum size of thisi Varray
    LEN := v1.LIMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Max size of Varray: ' || LEN);

    --Display the total number of the elements with populated values (value is not null)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total elements: ' || v1.COUNT);

    --Display the value of the last index
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last index value: ' || v1(v1.LAST));

    --Print out all of the contents of this Varray (including null elements)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This printout is all of the contents of this Varray:');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || 'Name');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || '----');
    FOR I IN 1 .. LEN LOOP
        IF v1.EXISTS(I) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || v1(I));
        ELSE
            v1.EXTEND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(9) || v1(I));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When I run the above, it runs up to the first loop and displays the name and underneath it the numbers, and then it stops.

It throws the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit
ORA-06512: at line 19
ORA-06512: at line 19
06532. 00000 -  "Subscript outside of limit"
*Cause:    A subscript was greater than the limit of a varray
           or non-positive for a varray or nested table.
*Action:   Check the program logic and increase the varray limit
           if necessary.
```

I cannot understand why this error is thrown.  I want to have an array of size 15 and to display the first 12 employee names from the table to populate `v1` and then display it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a description of what you want to do. Don't just post code and an Error, asking for someone to fix it ^^

Comment: Are you sure your cursor is returning 15 records?  Try adding rownum <16 to cursor. For printing towards the end use v1.First..v1.Last?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in these lines (`DECLARE` section):

```
TYPE Lname IS VARRAY(15)        --> 15

LEN NUMBER(2);                  -->  2
I NUMBER(2);                    -->  2
```

It works OK if number of array elements is lower than **15** (which you set in the first line above). However, if number of elements is higher than that number, you're trying to use an element whose *number* goes beyond that limit.

---

What to do? Enlarge *everything*, e.g.

- set varray to at least `count(*) from employees where department = 50` (I suggest a lot more)
- remove precision for those variables

For example:

```
TYPE Lname IS VARRAY(1000)             --> 1000
    OF employees.last_name%TYPE;
    v1 Lname:= Lname();
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT employee_id
    FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = 50;

LEN NUMBER;                           --> no precision
I NUMBER;                             --> no precision
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are apparently not writing the array to a table just make it and associative array. That doesn't impose a limit on the number of entries.

```
type lname is table of employees.lname%type
      index by pls_integer;
 i pls_integer;
```